# NetLogo: creation of lattice/grid resources world without using turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create a "gridded" world of resources, in specific distance from the central patch and keep distances equal between these patches. Due to calculation demand, I prefer not to use turtles to create this patchy world. I expect to create something like this:

[image]

Equally, I would like to define distance between patches as a slider tool. I was wandering to use turtle lattice walk and then turn patches to different color, but is there any way how to do that without turtles ? Thanks for any suggestions !

My not totally working exemple:

```
  to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor green]
    foreach [5 10 15] [
      repeat 9 [
        make-red-patch ?
      ]
    ]
  reset-ticks
end  

to make-red-patch [dist]
  crt 1 [
    fd dist
    rt 90
    while [pcolor = red] [
      bk dist
      rt 90
      fd 2 * dist
    ]
    set pcolor red
    die
  ]
end
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use turtles?

Comment: I plan to use 601 x 601 patches world with expected  about 1 million of actives turtles. And I was scarried that if I will use turtles even for creation of my  diversified landspaces, it will be even more computation demanding. What do you think? I really appreciate all your help and advices @SethTisue

Comment: If the turtles are only being used during setup, I don't think there will be a problem. After a turtle dies, it no longer uses any memory.

Comment: Thank you ! I figured it - just ask turtles [die] :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you need, first you mentioned you don't want to use turtles and in your own answer you have problem with the patch without a turtle.

There might be another way to approach this question:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches with [pxcor mod Grid = 0 and pycor mod Grid = 0] [set pcolor red]
end
```

And these are examples with different Grid size: 
[image: Grid size 9]

[image: Grid size 4]

Comment: Thank you a lot @Marzi !! :)) your answer is exactly what was I looking for ! :)

Answer (score 1):

After more detailed search I found my answer here: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Setting-up-agents-in-a-grid-formation-td4864083.html

They consider to distribute turtles, not patches and then attribute patches turtles' qualities.

Here is the code:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  [ let $n 0  ; actual number of turtles on this patch
    let $s 0  ; current number of turtles on a side of square pattern - 1
    set heading 0
    ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
    repeat 16   ; number of needed turtles
    [ hatch 1 jump Grid ; make one turtle and move
      set $n $n + 1 ; increment count of curent side
      ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
      if $n > $s  ; if side finished...
      [ 
        right 90 set $n 0 ; turn and reset count
        ask patch-here [set pcolor red]
        ; if headed up or down, increment side count
        if heading mod 180 = 0 [ set $s $s + 1 
          ]
      ]
    ]
   die
  ]
end
```

which produce:
[image]

I still don't know how to deal with 1 patch without turtle (bottom right corner), but this exemple helped me a lot ! :)