# How do I create a grid of patches in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create a patch grid, in NetLogo, at a set distance from each other. I'd like it to look something like:

[image]

I looked at [NetLogo: creation of lattice/grid resources world without using turtles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213757/netlogo-creation-of-lattice-grid-resources-world-without-using-turtles) but the code provided didn't work when I tried to replicate it:

```
ask patches with [pxcor mod Grid = 0 and pycor mod Grid = 0] [set pcolor red]
```

as "Grid" is not defined. Any help would be very much appreciated!
UPDATE: The questions do address the same problem, however the answer to the original question was not explicit/ repeatable by other users without assistance. The answers below clarify issues from that post and provide a code that can be used by anyone as well as an explanation of that code.

Comment: `Grid`, in the answer you're referring to, represents the grid size. You have to define it yourself (e.g., `let Grid 10`) or make it a slider...

Comment: duplicate of [NetLogo: creation of lattice/grid resources world without using turtles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213757/netlogo-creation-of-lattice-grid-resources-world-without-using-turtles) — this could have just been a comment there

Comment: perfect thank you for clarifying Nicolas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Nicolas's clarification above, I managed to produce the desired grid
[image]

```
to make_patches
ask patches [set depth 0 ]
let Grid Grid_size
ask patches with [pxcor mod Grid = 0 and pycor mod Grid = 0] [set depth     1] 
ask patches [  
  if depth = 0 [set pcolor gray]
  if depth = 1 [set pcolor blue - 2]
            ]
end
```

I used an input box (see picture) to allow easy modification of the grid size.